# Ghostscript fails to convert some PDFs

Tags: php, linux, pdf, fonts, ghostscript

### Background

I've been using Ghostscript for some time to convert PDFs to PNGs and GIFs.

I'm doing this on RHEL6 Unix via an exec command in PHP:

```
exec("/usr/bin/gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dQUIET -sDEVICE=png256 -sOutputFile=\"".$out."\" ".$in, $return);
```

$out and $in resolve to paths to the PDF input and PNG output.

However, some PDFs no longer seem to convert, giving the following error:

```
Error: /invalidaccess in --run--
Operand stack:
--dict:8/17(L)-- F2 85.117 --dict:6/6(L)-- --dict:6/6(L)-- CenturyGothic --dict:11/12(ro)(G)-- --nostringval-- CIDFontObject --dict:6/6(L)-- --dict:6/6(L)-- 14280 --dict:6/6(L)-- --nostringval-- PDFCIDFontName CenturyGothic
Execution stack:
%interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1862 1 3 %oparray_pop 1861 1 3 %oparray_pop 1845 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 1 2 --nostringval-- %for_pos_int_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push --nostringval-- %loop_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
--dict:1149/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- --dict:106/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:286/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:22/25(L)-- --dict:4/6(L)-- --dict:21/40(L)-- --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--
Current allocation mode is local
```

My version of Ghostscript is:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.16 (2015-03-30)
Copyright (C) 2015 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
Usage: gs [switches] [file1.ps file2.ps ...]
Most frequently used switches: (you can use # in place of =)
 -dNOPAUSE           no pause after page   | -q       `quiet', fewer messages
 -g<width>x<height>  page size in pixels   | -r<res>  pixels/inch resolution
 -sDEVICE=<devname>  select device         | -dBATCH  exit after last file
 -sOutputFile=<file> select output file: - for stdout, |command for pipe,
                                         embed %d or %ld for page #
Input formats: PostScript PostScriptLevel1 PostScriptLevel2 PostScriptLevel3 PDF
Default output device: bbox
Available devices:
   alc1900 alc2000 alc4000 alc4100 alc8500 alc8600 alc9100 ap3250 appledmp
   atx23 atx24 atx38 bbox bit bitcmyk bitrgb bitrgbtags bj10e bj10v bj10vh
   bj200 bjc600 bjc800 bjc880j bjccmyk bjccolor bjcgray bjcmono bmp16 bmp16m
   bmp256 bmp32b bmpgray bmpmono bmpsep1 bmpsep8 ccr cdeskjet cdj1600 cdj500
   cdj550 cdj670 cdj850 cdj880 cdj890 cdj970 cdjcolor cdjmono cdnj500 cfax
   chp2200 cif cljet5 cljet5c cljet5pr coslw2p coslwxl cp50 declj250 deskjet
   devicen dfaxhigh dfaxlow dj505j djet500 djet500c dl2100 dnj650c epl2050
   epl2050p epl2120 epl2500 epl2750 epl5800 epl5900 epl6100 epl6200 eplcolor
   eplmono eps2write eps9high eps9mid epson epsonc escp escpage faxg3
   faxg32d faxg4 fmlbp fmpr fpng fs600 gdi hl1240 hl1250 hl7x0 hpdj1120c
   hpdj310 hpdj320 hpdj340 hpdj400 hpdj500 hpdj500c hpdj510 hpdj520 hpdj540
   hpdj550c hpdj560c hpdj600 hpdj660c hpdj670c hpdj680c hpdj690c hpdj850c
   hpdj855c hpdj870c hpdj890c hpdjplus hpdjportable ibmpro ijs imagen
   inferno ink_cov inkcov itk24i itk38 iwhi iwlo iwlq jetp3852 jj100 jpeg
   jpegcmyk jpeggray la50 la70 la75 la75plus laserjet lbp310 lbp320 lbp8
   lex2050 lex3200 lex5700 lex7000 lips2p lips3 lips4 lips4v lj250 lj3100sw
   lj4dith lj4dithp lj5gray lj5mono ljet2p ljet3 ljet3d ljet4 ljet4d
   ljet4pjl ljetplus ln03 lp1800 lp1900 lp2000 lp2200 lp2400 lp2500 lp2563
   lp3000c lp7500 lp7700 lp7900 lp8000 lp8000c lp8100 lp8200c lp8300c
   lp8300f lp8400f lp8500c lp8600 lp8600f lp8700 lp8800c lp8900 lp9000b
   lp9000c lp9100 lp9200b lp9200c lp9300 lp9400 lp9500c lp9600 lp9600s
   lp9800c lps4500 lps6500 lq850 lxm3200 lxm5700m m8510 mag16 mag256
   md1xMono md2k md50Eco md50Mono md5k mgr4 mgr8 mgrgray2 mgrgray4 mgrgray8
   mgrmono miff24 mj500c mj6000c mj700v2c mj8000c ml600 necp6 npdl nullpage
   oce9050 oki182 oki4w okiibm oprp opvp paintjet pam pamcmyk32 pamcmyk4 pbm
   pbmraw pcl3 pcx16 pcx24b pcx256 pcx2up pcxcmyk pcxgray pcxmono pdfwrite
   pgm pgmraw pgnm pgnmraw photoex picty180 pj pjetxl pjxl pjxl300 pkm
   pkmraw pksm pksmraw plan plan9bm planc plang plank planm plib plibc plibg
   plibk plibm png16 png16m png256 png48 pngalpha pnggray pngmono pnm pnmraw
   ppm ppmraw pr1000 pr1000_4 pr150 pr201 ps2write psdcmyk psdcmykog psdrgb
   pxlcolor pxlmono r4081 rinkj rpdl samsunggdi sgirgb sj48 spotcmyk st800
   stcolor sunhmono t4693d2 t4693d4 t4693d8 tek4696 tiff12nc tiff24nc
   tiff32nc tiff48nc tiff64nc tiffcrle tiffg3 tiffg32d tiffg4 tiffgray
   tifflzw tiffpack tiffscaled tiffsep tiffsep1 txtwrite uniprint xcf xes
   xpswrite
Search path:
   %rom%Resource/Init/ : %rom%lib/ :
   /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/Init :
   /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/lib :
   /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/Font :
   /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts :
   /usr/local/share/fonts/default/ghostscript :
   /usr/local/share/fonts/default/Type1 :
   /usr/local/share/fonts/default/TrueType : /usr/lib/DPS/outline/base :
   /usr/openwin/lib/X11/fonts/Type1 : /usr/openwin/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType
Initialization files are compiled into the executable.
```

After much searching and debugging I think it has something to do with the CID fonts embedded in the original PDF supplied by my client:

> **name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID**
>
> CenturyGothic        TrueType        yes             no   no   11   0
>
> CenturyGothic                        CID TrueType      yes no  yes    26  0
>
> Arial-BoldMT                         CID TrueType      yes no  yes   195  0
>
> Arial-BoldMT                         TrueType          yes no  no    198  0
>
> Arial-Black                          TrueType          yes no  no    586  0

So, I remade the PDF and it works like a charm. The embedded fonts are different though, even though all I did was open the file in Illustrator and resave:

> **name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID**
>
> CDXNGM+CenturyGothic                 TrueType          yes yes no     94  0
>
> CDXNGM+Arial-BoldMT                  TrueType          yes yes no     95  0
>
> CDXNGM+Arial-Black                   TrueType          yes yes no     96  0

### Files

**Failing file:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/54hbdgtewplkrk0/failing.pdf?dl=0

**Working file:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9uwbyjytjer1zy/working.pdf?dl=0

### Questions

1. I'm not sure why the original file isn't using the embedded CID font, or just ignoring it as it seems it isn't even needed?
2. Why is Ghostscript not producing a font error but an invalidaccess error?
3. Is there a way I can strip the CID fonts in PHP or via exec before converting?
4. Is there a way to get Ghostscript to ignore the font issue and just make the best fist of it that it can?
5. Is there something I can do to ghostscript that will result in output?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'failing' file works well for me using the current source code, the 9.18 release *and* the 9.16 release (all built from source).

Which leads me to suspect that this is a packaging problem. The various Linux distributions package GS themselves and the packages do not always reflect the vanilla code. Packagers sometimes add their own patches, or alter the way that Ghostscript is built. In particular they often require that system shared libraries are used instead of the versions we ship with Ghostscript, and which are known to work. In this case its possible that a different version of FreeType is being used for example.

I would suggest that you get the Ghostscript source, build it yourself, and test that. If that works then you can complain to whoever maintains the Red Hat package (but please make sure you are using the **latest** package, I seem to recall that Red Hat are usually pretty up to date and you are using a version which is a year+ out of date).

So to answer your questions:

1. All the fonts are needed.
2. Ghostscript is producing an invalidaccess error (most likely) because it is trying to alter the contents of a font dictionary which has been defined as 'read only'. While this is *also* a font error what you get is the lowest level of error.
3. Stripping the fonts out is not a good solution. Firstly because the resulting image will have substituted fonts which will often be incorrect, secondly because its hard to do.
4. For PDF input if Ghostscript can ignore the error and continue, it will in general. This is a fatal error.
5. Yes, build Ghostscript from source. Even if that doesn't work we'll be in a better position to help you. If it doesn't work after you build from the canonical source, then please open a bug report.

I don't really think its worth a long debate about the merits or otherwise of CIDFonts, but this is not likely to be the real source of the problem.

Comment: Ken, Thanks so much for your really thorough response. I'll set about building 9.18 from source and see if it fixes the issue and let you know how I get on. It's really good to get a response from the developers, thanks.

Comment: Ken, I built GS 9.18 from source and I still get the same error. I did notice that the Resources folder was missing so I copied it from the source folder to where ge -h said it should be but still no luck.

Comment: OK I'm going to have to suggest you open a bug report for this one, and I'll ask someone with more Linux knowledge than me to look into it. Note that you should not need the Resources folder as the default is to build that into the binary as a ROM file system. gs -h should tell you where its looking, not where the folder has to go.

Comment: I've tried both your files (working.pdf and failing.pdf) on the gs 9.16 installed on my Ubuntu 15.10 distro, and neither give so much as a warning. Can you reproduce the problem outside of the PHP environment?